# Using MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE statement with ormlite

Tags: java, mysql, orm, load-data-infile, ormlite

Has anybody tried using `load data infile` MySQL statement with ormlite? I've looked up the ormlite reference guide but did not find any example on this. I'm a newbie, so please help out.

Comment: Any feedback on my answer moCha?  Please accept it if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think that the [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) `Dao.executeRaw()` method would work with this statement -- or any similar.  Here are the [javadocs for that routine](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#executeRaw%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...%29).  Something like:

```
int numRowsChanged =
   dao.executeRaw("load data infile '" + infile.getPath() + "'");
```